# How to programmatically increase the font size for the entire app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a MaterialApp in Flutter and want to scale up text throughout the entire app, base in user preferences.

**Base on the answer, I was able to create a Notifier like:**

```
class PreferencesNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  double textScaleFactor = 1.0;

  PreferencesNotifier();

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    textScaleFactor = prefs.getDouble('textScaleFactor') ?? 1.0;
  }

  setTextScaleFactor(double x) {
    textScaleFactor = x;
    notifyListeners();

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then(
      (prefs) {
        prefs.setDouble('textScaleFactor', textScaleFactor);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

...and then use a MediaQuery like:

```
MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
          textScaleFactor: preferencesNotifier.textScaleFactor,
        ),
        child: Widget()
      ),
```

Comment: You may be able to modify the font size(s) in the material theme data using a global variable that is changed based on user preferences. I haven't tested this but if I had the need I would try that method first. Otherwise, you are gonna have to put a modifier in each text field

Comment: Thank you @GrahamD, I tried your suggestion, but I realize it was easier to use MediaQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To programmatically increase the font size for the entire app in Flutter, you can use a MediaQuery widget at the root of your app. This widget allows you to access the device's media and display information, such as the screen size and the current text scale factor.

```
MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
    // Increase the text scale factor to 1.5
    textScaleFactor: 1.5,
  ),
  child: YourApp(),
),
```